# Can I show user data to other users in Stormpath?

Tags: swift, stormpath, express-stormpath, stormpath-express

I'm trying to integrate Stormpath to an iOS app (Swift), and would like to be able to show one user's data to another user.

In other words, can I show 1 user another user's information by searching my userlist for certain factors (such as age or geographic location) like I would be able to with mySQL?

Is this possible? I haven't been able to find documentation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you would implement an API endpoint in your backend application that exposes whatever information you need (for example, another user's data), and then have your iOS app make a request to your API to retrieve that information and display it on the device.

Stormpath is really flexible and will allow you to do pretty much whatever you want with your user data, so as long as you can write an API call on your backend to retrieve the data, your iOS app can show whatever you want =)

SOURCE: I work @ Stormpath.

Comment: So you're saying that Stormpath allows for open-ended API calls that any of my users can access?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that you (the developer who controls the server-side API service) can write code which can access any user's information. So you could write an API call that only allows a particular user to access the API endpoint, but returns another user's information to the application.